# How to use a Select inside a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom-events

I am trying to figure out how I could place a select inside a button so that I could use the select to select stuff, but the button outside the select would do other stuff onclick.

This entire white area is button and the select can be seen inside it. I would like to use all the white area as a button and if select is clicked the select would open.

Right now button onclick is triggered if I click select.

Can I create something using jQuery to detect if select is clicked and else button click is triggered?

[image]

```
<button type="button" onclick="doStuff()" class="btn-lg btn-menu col-xs-6">
    Button
    <select>
        <option value="mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
    </select>
</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first solution didn't work cross-browser, because HTML5 doesn't allow interactive elements (such as `select`) within buttons.

This new solution replaces buttons with spans as Jason van der Zeeuw suggested:

```js
$('span').click(function(event) {
   if(event.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
       alert('span pressed!');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  Button
   <select>
      <option value="mon">Monday</option>
      <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
   </select>
</span>
```

Comment: But clicking the select also triggers the button click event now?

Comment: Correct, it triggers the button click, but `event.target.tagName` will be `SELECT` if you click the select box, so you can run code only if it's equal to `BUTTON`.

Comment: Even if I click the select the alert will trigger.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. It seems it works on Chrome at least. But I think this is related to what Andrew Johnston said. Firefox follows standard and Chrome maybe doesn't?

Comment: Looks like it.  It works in Chrome, but it also fails in IE.  Based on @AndrewJohnston's response, you probably shouldn't use a `select` within a `button`.  I'll see if I can come up with a Firefox and IE solution, though.

Comment: I tried it by also combining Jason van der Zeeuw's answer. Your original solution works if I just replace buttons with spans. I think thats the most elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [W3C HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-button-element), the button element cannot have interactive descendants:

```
Content model:
Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.
```

Since select is an [interactive element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#interactive-content-0), putting a select inside a button is not valid html.

Just out of curiosity, I tried playing around with the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property to increase the stack order of the select.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yeruli/2/edit?html,css,output)

Firefox followed the standard and did not allow interaction on the select.

Of course, you can use another structure for the parent element.

Comment: +1, that's good to know.  My answer may not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a span-tag and style it as a button.
That way you keep your code clean and valid and still achieve your goal.

```
<span class="btn-lg btn-menu col-xs-6" onclick="doStuff()">
    Button
    <select>
        <option value="mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Changing the button to span doesn't change anything. Onclick event on span will also trigger when clicking select.

Comment: Try a different selector:
$('.button').not('select').click(function(){})
That way, the click event won't bind to the select

Answer (score -1):

A simplistic solution:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doStuff(event)" class="btn-lg btn-menu col-xs-6">
    Button
    <select>
         <option value="mon">Monday</option>
         <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
         <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
    </select>
</button>

<script>
    function doStuff(event) {
        if(event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
</script>
```